# TCL : Regarding init.tcl file in TCL

Tags: tcl

Can anyone explain me what is the use of `init.tcl`?

When actually it is loaded by the `TCL` interpreter?

The description for this file is shown as

```
startup file for TCL .
```

But According to my knowledge `.tclshrc` is the start up file.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: http://wiki.tcl.tk/15746

Answer (score 5):

Actually, init.tcl is the first file that is loaded by a Tcl_Interp*.
Its job is to setup the different package loading mechanisms.

Some programs, most notably `tclsh`, will source the `.tclshrc`. This is usually done using [`Tcl_SourceRCFile`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/SourceRCFile.htm).

So `init.tcl` is sourced for every Tcl interpreter, while the `.tclshrc` is only sourced by some programs that explicitly do that.

<sub>* does not apply to safe interpreters</sub>

Comment: +1 to your answer.. Just i could not hold back myself from asking.. Where i can find .tclshrc file? Is it like .bashrc file? Actually i couldn't find it next to .bashrc file..

Comment: exactly. tclsh set the value of tcl_rcFileName to `~/.tclshrc` Or on windows to `~/tclshrc.tcl`

Comment: Let me check throughout my system. might be some where else.. :P I am using Centos5

Comment: wow! it was not there.. i created it and added all the commands to it... by default it is loading all the commands to tcl. Question went different way. Sorry

Comment: The `.tclshrc` is only loaded in _interactive_ interpreters, whereas `init.tcl` is loaded in all (and it doesn't just set up package loading; that's just what the bulk of code in it does).

Comment: @DonalFellows : 'It's job is to setup the different package loading mechanisms.' I want to know the loading mechanism , i mean functionalities of init.tcl . Can you please elaborate this statement ?